# Error trying to do an hybrid AngularJS/Angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

Im trying to do an hybrid app using AngularJS & Angular(2).
I already have a big AngularJS app and I just want to use a component from an Angular app.

Using https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html, I have created two new files

app.module.ts

```
import { UpgradeModule } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    UpgradeModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {
  ngDoBootstrap() {}
}
```

and main.ts

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { UpgradeModule } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import App from './app.js';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(platformRef => {
  const upgrade = platformRef.injector.get(UpgradeModule) as UpgradeModule;
  upgrade.bootstrap(document.documentElement, [App]);
});
```

and I have deleted the old bootstrap.js file

```
import angular from 'angular';
import App from './app';

angular.element(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document, [App], { strictDi: true });
});
```

The entry of my webpack build is now *main.ts*.

When I start my app, I have ana issue :

```
ERROR in ./client/app/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './app.module' in '/home/bsousa/Projects/S6/client/app'
 @ ./client/app/main.ts 5:21-44
```

Do someone know why ?

Here is the tsconfig.json, maybe it can help

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowJs": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "allowUnreachableCode": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Files structure

```
/
   client
      app
         ...
         app.js
         app.module.ts
         main.ts
   gulpfile.js
   webpack.config.js
```

Comment: What does your folder structure look like?

Comment: Yes. I have a standalone Angular app and I want to include the owl app in another project, the AngularJS app. The 2 apps are already quite as big so I can't convert an app.

Comment: i have added the folder structure

Comment: disregard my comment… that's your old app, I get it...

Comment: Either try `import {AppModule} from './' ` or `import {AppModule} from './app.module.ts'`

Comment: Not working. That's weird because the IDE recognize the import.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137354/discussion-between-bksoux-and-kevingreen).

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know why the import did not work but when I set everything in the main.ts file, it works

```
import 'zone.js';
import 'angular';
import App from './app.js';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { UpgradeModule } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    UpgradeModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {
  ngDoBootstrap() {
  }
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(platformRef => {
  const upgrade = platformRef.injector.get(UpgradeModule) as UpgradeModule;
  upgrade.bootstrap(document.documentElement, [App.name], { strictDi: true });
});
```

My AngularJS is bootstrapped with Angular.

Now I'm trying to import my Angular app into my project as a node package but I think I have to do some improvements with the export.

I would like to import the root component, do I have to import the root module as well ?